# C# the name brojevi does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

I want to make a simple program (lottery numbers generator) that takes numbers within a specific range and shuffles them "n" number of times, after each shuffle it selects one random number and moves it from the list of a given range to a new list, and does this for "n" number of times (until it selects specific amount of numbers, 7 to be exact). I have found an algorithm that does exactly that (an extension method or shuffling generic lists). But I'm not that into programming and I have a problem with displaying the results (the list with the drawn numbers) to a TextBox or Label, however I have got it to work with a MessageBox. But with TextBox/Label I get the error "The name *** does not exist in current context". I've googled for a solution but no help what so ever.

Here's the code:

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         List<int> numbers;
         numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 39).ToList();
         numbers.Shuffle();
      }

      private void brojevi_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {          
      }
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class for shuffling lists
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of list to shuffle</typeparam>
public static class ListShufflerExtensionMethods
{
    //for getting random values
    private static Random _rnd = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// Shuffles the contents of a list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the list to sort</typeparam>
    /// <param name="listToShuffle">The list to shuffle</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfTimesToShuffle">How many times to shuffle the list,    by default this is 5 times</param>
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this List<T> listToShuffle, int numberOfTimesToShuffle = 7)
    {          
        //make a new list of the wanted type
        List<T> newList = new List<T>();

        //for each time we want to shuffle
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimesToShuffle; i++)
        {
            //while there are still items in our list
            while (listToShuffle.Count >= 33)
            {
                //get a random number within the list
                int index = _rnd.Next(listToShuffle.Count);

                //add the item at that position to the new list
                newList.Add(listToShuffle[index]);

                //and remove it from the old list
                listToShuffle.RemoveAt(index);
            }

            //then copy all the items back in the old list again
            listToShuffle.AddRange(newList);

            //display contents of a list
            string line = string.Join(",", newList.ToArray());
            brojevi.Text = line;

            //and clear the new list
            //to make ready for next shuffling
            newList.Clear();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is probably a scope issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28VS.71%29.aspx.  However, it's hard to tell, because you don't say where the error(s) are.

Comment: Where is the code for displaying the MessageBox?

Comment: is it literally `the name * does not exist` or does the `*` mean a specific symbol?

Comment: More code than necessary to demonstrate the problem. Please edit it down to the smallest code required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `brojevi` (either `TextBox` or `Label`) isn't defined in the scope of the extension method, it is a `Control` so it should be defined in your `Form`. So, when you shuffle your numbers, put them in the `TextBox` during the execution of the `button1_Click` event handler

Remove the lines:

```
    string line = string.Join(",", newList.ToArray());
    brojevi.Text = line;
```

**EDIT:**

You could change the extension method like this to return the string of drawn items or list of drawn items. Lets go for the list because you might want to use the numbers for other things. Also, I don't see the point in shuffling 7 times because you will be able to see only last shuffling. Therefore I think that one is enough. Check the code:

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this List<T> listToShuffle)
        {
            //make a new list of the wanted type
            List<T> newList = new List<T>();


            //while there are still items in our list
            while (listToShuffle.Count >= 33)
            {
                //get a random number within the list
                int index = _rnd.Next(listToShuffle.Count);

                //add the item at that position to the new list
                newList.Add(listToShuffle[index]);

                //and remove it from the old list
                listToShuffle.RemoveAt(index);
            }

            //then copy all the items back in the old list again
            listToShuffle.AddRange(newList);

            return newList;
        }
```

And in button1_Click1 event handler we can have:

```
List<int> numbers;
numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 39).ToList();
List<int> drawnNumbers = numbers.Shuffle();
string line = string.Join(",", drawnNumbers.ToArray());
brojevi.Text = line;
```

Comment: This code displays the contents of "numbers.Shuffle" (39 numbers in random order after being shuffled) but I need to display the contents of the "newList" because it contains only the 7 drawn numbers. TextBox "brojevi" is like you've wrote, out of scope of the Class that shuffles lists, so I need a way either to get the TextBox "brojevi" into the scope of the Class or to export the values from "newList" to TextBox "brojevi".

Comment: @JamesDawkins Check the answer now, I think that it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

ListShufflerExtensionMethods doesn't know about your textbox (brojevi) because it's out of scope. You could restructure and make Shuffle return a value, then set the value of the textbox' text in callers scope.